# How to check if server accessed by IP with mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, header, ip

I have web servers behind a load-balancer. They all have the following rule to help with SEO (www.example.org pointing to the load-balancer):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !www.example.org
RewriteRule ^/(.*)          http://www.example.org/$1  [L,R=302]
```

I want to be able to access these servers directly by IP, in which case the above rule cannot be applied otherwise people would be redirected to the load-balancer. I tried the following condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} 1.2.3.4
RewriteRule (.*)           $1 [L]
```

The problem is that when accessed by IP, the `%{HTTP_HOST}` is not set and `mod_rewrite` skips the rule.

**Q: How can I check for a missing or empty host header?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `REMOTE_ADDR`.

like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 1.2.3.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can prevent the redirect to the load balancer by adding another condition to check for not empty %{HTTP_HOST} as below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)          http://www.example.org/$1  [L,R=302]
```

Your first condition has an "error" as you didn't backslash the dot, it actually means match any character, even though it is very unlikely that anyone will be able to reach your server without the dot. [NC] is added in the end so the condition is case insensitive.

Hope it helps.